# Let ${f_n} \in L(E)$ if $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{E}\lvert f{_n}-f\rvert=0$ then $f \in L(E)$

Tags: real-analysis

I prove by the following:

We need to show $\int_{E}f^+\lt\infty$ and $\int_{E}f^-\lt\infty$

Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{E}|f_n-f|=0 $

So, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{E}f_n=\int_{E}f$

$\int_{E}f^+\lt \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{E}f_n \lt \infty$
and $\int_{E}f^-\lt \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{E}f_n \lt \infty$

So, $f$ is integrable

Is that right? I feel I still miss something

Comment: If $g \in L^1$ and $g-f \in L^1,$ then $f\in L^1.$ Done!

Comment: @zhw. Is that dominating convergence theorem?